# Is there a way to send variables to javascript files?

Tags: javascript

is it possible to do something like this
to send the value id=3 to the js file

```
<script src="http://site.com/js/loader.js?id=3" ....
```

otherwise what's the approach to do that?

Answer (score 2):

No, that won't work. 
Just set the variables before you load the file:

```
<script>var id = 3;</script>
<script src="http://site.com/js/loader.js" ....
```

Since all the scripts share a global namespace, you'll be able to access the `id` variable from inside your `loader.js` file.

Of course you should think about the style and implications of using global vars to achieve that. Using a global object that hold these config variables might be a cleaner approach.

Answer (score 0):

If that is just a javascript file, you can just define the variable before load it.

```
<script>
var id = 3;
</script>
<script src="http://site.com/js/loader.js" ....
```

Answer (score 0):

It would work, but not if your `.js` URL is just for a static file.  If you wrote server-side code that output JavaScript, then you could output custom JavaScript based on the query string.

This is probably overkill for what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

k so this question has pretty much been answered. But there is another approach, which may or may not be suitable for you. If you want to render script conditionally or fetch a certain script for a certain id. You can declare it in a serverside script

```
 http://site.com/js/loader.js.php?id=1
```

In the loader.js.php
Just use the following line in the beginning

```
 <? 
header("Content-type: text/javascript");//To declare it is a javascript file
$id=$_REQUEST['id'];
?>
//Normal js continues after  this

//When you need to use the variable, just use
var id=<?=$id?>
```